# Homebrew: Install formula with Python bindings for specific Python version?

Tags: homebrew, python

I'd like to install a Homebrew formula that has Python bindings. OpenImageIO is an example:

`brew install openimageio`

As of this writing, the version of Python that Homebrew is wanting to install is 3.12. Only problem is, I have to use many proprietary tools, which do not work on Python 3.12. I still have to use Python 3.9.

I've tried:

`brew pin python@3.9`

This works to pin Python 3.9 to a specific subversion, say 3.9.18, but this does not work to pin Python 3 to Python 3.9.18. Python 3 always seems to be whatever Homebrew thinks it should be at the moment. So, when I run brew install openimageio, Homebrew will install those openimageio Python bindings which have to be compiled against a specific version of the Python libraries, and into the site-packages directory for Python 3.12.

Is there a way to convince Homebrew to install openimageio and compile the Python bindings for Python 3.9?

Comment: The `openimageio` formula declares a specific dependency on Python 3.12.  It's not that it looks at where `python3` points, and makes a decision.